# Saving drive space by uninstalling games from Steam

Tags: steam, windows-7

If I download a Steam game, play it, and delete it/uninstall it, will it be completely gone from my computer? I want to download Amnesia demo, but once I've played it, I'm gonnna delete it to save drive space. Will everything be gone? All the files? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly not.

Steam tends to leave at least some things lying around, as it doesn't actually "uninstall", though it obviously depends on the game in question.

Many games also insert their own data into %APPDATA%, %USERPROFILE% or elsewhere, which are unlikely to be removed when you delete the game from Steam.

**Edit to add:** most of the time, these files will be insignificantly small. But if you want to be super clean, be prepared to look around for the artfacts left behind and don't trust/expect Steam to manage it.

Comment: That said, most of these files are likely to be very small.

Comment: I don't know, Dirt3 left 1.2GB lying around when I uninstalled it from Steam. Really depends on the game.

Comment: Geeeeez, what were those files?!  I still stand by my statement that most of the time that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Sounds like Dirt3 needs to learn how to pickup after itself. I have never had a game leave behind anything that massive.

Comment: @Shinrai I don't disagree, most of the time the files will be small.

Comment: Some games save more data than others in a savegame. I'm something of a packrat, and recently going through old directories I found about ten gigs' worth of Dragon Age 1 saves...

Comment: Fallout 3 or New Vegas both leave large save files - think I had 5 gigs of F3 saves to delete